# Django Back and Next button in html file

Tags: django, function, datetime, button

I read django document, I know django has get_next_by_foo with foo is datetime and dont have not null=True.
I created in model 2 function get_previous, and get_next but when I call it in html file, i doesnt show anything
In my model.py

```
class Contracts(models.Model):
id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
contract=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True, null=True)
debt=models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True)
objects=models.Manager()
class Meta:
    ordering=["-created_at"]

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/contract_detail/%s/" % self.contract
```

in my view.html

```
def next_back(request, id=None):
    queryset = get_object_or_404(Contracts, id=contract)
    the_next = queryset.get_next_by_created_at()
    the_prev= queryset.get_previous_by_created_at()
    context ={
        "title": queryset.title,
        "instance": queryset,
        "the_next" : the_next,
        "the_prev": the_prev,
    }
    return render(request, "contract_detail.html", context)
def contract_detail(request, pk):
    queryset = Contracts.objects.get(contract=pk)
    context = {
        "queryset": queryset,
    }
    return render(request, "contract_detail.html", context)
```

in my url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('demo',views.showDemoPage),
#path("",views.home, name='home'),
path('customer/', views.index, name='index'),
path('customer1/', views.list_contract, name='list_contract'),
path('add_items/', views.add_items, name='add_items'),
path('search/', views.searchcontract, name='search'),
path('contract_detail/<str:pk>/', views.contract_detail, name="contract_detail"),
url(r'^export/csv/$', views.export_search_csv, name='export_search_csv'),
```

and in my contract_detail.html

```
  <a href="{{ the_next.get_absolute_url }}">Next</a>
  <a href="{{ the_prev.get_absolute_url }}">Previous</a>
```

Do I misunderstand its concept? If I do, how can I deal with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the template, you are using the URL pattern of `contract_detail` for the next and previous links. But you have defined the logic for getting the next and previous objects in the view `next_back` which is not mapped to any URL pattern. This might be the confusion I think. Post the code for `contract_detail` view. It might help.

Comment: I just edit my question. I think this is the issue but I don't know how to fix it. This is my first project in django and I am still newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your URLs, views, and templates.

#### urls.py

```
....
path('contract_detail/<str:contract_id>/', views.contract_detail, name="contract_detail"),
....
```

#### views.py

```
def contract_detail(request, contract_id=None):
    contract = get_object_or_404(Contracts, contract=contract_id)
    the_next = contract.get_next_by_created_at()
    the_prev = contract.get_previous_by_created_at()
    context = {
        "contract": contract,
        "the_next" : the_next,
        "the_prev": the_prev,
    }
    return render(request, "contract_detail.html", context)
```

In the template, you can use the variable `contract` to access the instance. You are getting a single instance of the model. So naming it as `queryset` doesn't make any sense.